# Older pydev version for eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, python-3.x, pydev

I am getting started with eclipse pydev and python generally.! I want to try a code which is compatible with python 2. That means I should download an older version of pydev? I have both installed python 2.7 and python 3 in my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyDev supports Python 2.x as well as Python 3.x in its current release (you just have to set which version you're using in the project properties -- see: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html for more details).

-- so, you should definitely use the latest version, not an older version.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.pydev.org/history_pydev.html:
As of PyDev 10.0.0 its debugger no longer supports Python < 3.6

Unfortunately the link "http://www.pydev.org/updates/" only provides the latest version.

Browse to https://www.pydev.org/update_sites/ with your browser
and use the link for the version you want

Comment: I do not understand why every version of liclipse has this version 10.0